# access Cloud Firestore from Wordpress code

Tags: wordpress, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Can I access Cloud Firestore from WordPress especially from the WordPress plugin called Boldgrid? I´m not a http knowledgeable person so my question might sound silly.

I have this WordPress Boldgrid site and wanted to make queries to Cloud Firestore and present result.

I like any help to get started since I Google this but find actually nothing.